# Cas server clustered deployment service registry

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I have a problem how to synchronize json services files between cas server nodes in clusters.

How to do it, is the cas server config services directory can accept a url folder containing the services?

Also can we work with 2 registration strategies (JSON and JPA) ?

Regards.

Comment: what is your CAS version? Have you checked with this [doc](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/planning/High-Availability-Guide.html) yet

Comment: i am using 5.1.x version.
Yes i've checked this document but i want to know if it is possible in cas to synchronise between to service definition providers json and jpa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two service registries, unless you write one that does support that sort of thing. You need to pick one. If the one you choose is some sort of database (relational, noSql) then there is no need for replication since all nodes have access to the same database instance. If you pick something that is node-specific like JSON, you need to figure out how to replicate the definitions across the cluster, with rsync or hazelcast.

https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/Configuring-Service-Replication.html